# Display and select supported resolutions in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I'm a bit annoyed that the display menulet in Mountain Lion no longer lets you adjust the screen resolution.

So I'm working on a simple menulet using NSStatusItem, but I've never really delved into the world of adjusting the display resolution.

How can I create a simple menu which will list a screen's supported resolutions and change to that one when you select it?

Comment: You actually still can - you select "scaled" in the display resolution  submenu and it lists supported resolutions (I mean, in System Preferences)

Comment: I know, but I prefer the convenience of swapping the resolution via the menubar.

Comment: oh, ok :) Just wanted to let you know.